# How to fix this blender bridge edge loop problem?

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm stuck with this problem and i don't know how to fix it

[image: screenshot]

How to solve this problem? I don't know how to describe it, but this problem is too confusing for modeling. I am only beginner for this and this problem is too difficult for me.

Comment: hello, I think it's just a matter of settings in the Operator box, could you please share your file (your 2 cylinders before the bridge)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a problem with the operator settings you have, specifically the interpolation setting. Try changing it to Blend Surface. Below are some images to show the difference.[image]
This image shows an object similar to yours and has the same unchanged operator settings[image]

Second image shows the same object with but with interpolation changed to blend surface.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the two upper surfaces (this also selects all edges).
2. Select *Edge* -> *Bridge Edge Loop* and apply the following settings:

   - Twist: *0*
   - Number of cuts: *(any)*
   - Interpolation: *Blend Surface*

[image]